# Is topological semi-conjugacy sufficient for the case described below, or does one need full conjugacy?

Tags: general-topology, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm taking an undergraduate course in nonlinear dynamics, and the idea of topological conjugacy between (one-dimensional) iterated maps was introduced as follows:

Let ${I}$ and ${J}$ be intervals. We have two mapping functions ${f:I\rightarrow I}$ and ${g:J\rightarrow J}$. We say that ${f}$ and ${g}$ are *conjugate* if $\exists$ a homeomorphism ${h:I\rightarrow J}$ such that ${h}$ satisfies the conjugacy equation $${h \circ f = g \circ h}$$

I checked [the Wikipedia article on topological conjugacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy) and found that the definition given above looks more like that of *semi*conjugacy. Semiconjugacy requires the map ${h}$ defined above to be a surjection, and not necessarily a homeomorphism. (I have not taken any formal courses in topology, but I understand a homeomorphism to be a continuous invertible map with a continuous inverse). Wikipedia says that for topological conjugacy, we require $${f = h^-1 \circ g \circ h}$$

This notion was introduced to us in order to relate different kinds of maps - if two maps are topologically conjugate, then solving the dynamics of one of them, i.e. finding fixed points, periodic orbits etc. enables us to trivially find those of the other.

**My question is:** Is topological conjugacy necessary in order to use the solved dynamics of one map to solve those of a conjugate map, or does semiconjugacy suffice for the same purposes? That is to say, if ${f}$ and ${g}$ are semiconjugate and ${f}$ is chaotic, then can I say ${g}$ is chaotic? Or do I need conjugacy to make this statement?

An example given in class was the "conjugacy" between the tent map and the logistic map. The tent map is defined as: 
$${f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      2x & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
      2(1-x) & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1 
   \end{cases}
}$$

And the logistic map is: $${g(x)= 4x(1-x), 0 \leq x \leq 1}$$

This was demonstrated by defining ${h:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]}$ as:

$${h(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-cos2 \pi x)}$$

and showing that ${h \circ f = g \circ h}$. Here, ${h}$ is continous and surjective but not injective, and therefore not invertible, and also not a homeomorphism. So we have established semiconjugacy between the logistic and tent maps. It is quite easy to show that the tent map is chaotic, and this is how it is argued that the logistic map, too, exhibits chaos. Can we make this leap from the tent map to the logistic map, given that we have established merely semiconjugacy, and not conjugacy?

Comment: I'm not sure from your question, but it seems to me you might be giving importance to the fact that the wikipedia articles define topological semi-conjugacy as a relation of the form $h \circ f =  g \circ h$, whereas full conjugacy as $f = h^-1 \circ g \circ h$. When h is invertible these are of course equivalent, that is if h is a homeomorphisme then $f = h^-1 \circ g \circ h$ <=>  $h \circ f =  g \circ h$.

Comment: Note also that if $f$ and $g$ are topologically semi-conjugate (but not fully conjugate) then $f$ and $g$ don't play symmetric roles - the order of composition matters in the definition. It's been a long time since I've studied dynamical systems but IIRC some properties carry over from one to the other but not vice versa

Comment: I get that the relation ${h \circ f = g \circ h}$ holds for the case where ${h}$ is a homeomorphism. Yes, I thought something similar too - that semi-conjugacy won't permit the transfer of properties in a symmetrical fashion from one map to another. I want to confirm whether or not this hunch is true - because if it is true then we have a problem. To take the example in the question itself, the chaos of the tent map implies the same in the logistic map, but we may not be able to state the converse. And in this case, the statement "${f}$ and ${g}$ are topologically semiconjugate" bothers me.

Comment: Just came across this question, but the answer is almost surely yes, depending on your definition of chaos. Using Devaney's popular definition, we must have dense periodic orbits of all orders, transitivity, and sensitivity to initial conditions. Periodic points are clearly preserved (iteration is; differentiate via chain rule) and [one can show transitivity is preserved](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188105/269764). Sensitivity is not actually preserved on its own, but one can show dense periodic orbits + transitivity imply sensitivity so semiconjugacy suffices.